# Is Dash.js player Support HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) and MSS (Microsoft Smooth Streaming)?

Tags: javascript, html, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, dash.js

I am new in [Dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki) platform . I have written sample `HTML file` for Adaptive Streaming in HTML5 with `Dash.js` using `.mpd` URL .

```
var url = "https://dash.akamaized.net/envivio/EnvivioDash3/manifest.mpd"
```

This is working fine in browser . Now i want to know can i stream `HTTP Live Streaming (HLS)` and `Microsoft Smooth Streaming (MSS)` using `Dash.js` framework player in `HTML5` ? Can you suggest some of the useful reference for that too ?

Comment: `dash.js` is for MPEG-DASH. See this discussion: https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/issues/483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dash.js can play MSS if you include the optional MSS package. See https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/blob/development/samples/smooth-streaming/mss.html for an example.

It is unable to play HLS - you would need a different player for that.